# Failed to connect MySQL SSL connection to Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a customer trying to connect a Google Data Studio data source to MySQL, via SSL connection, however, they are receiving an Error Code: `a113b4a0`.

What does this error ID represent, and how do I help them resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the issue with more details, such as the settings used (replacing any sensitive information), adding screenshots for more clarity, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution -

Apparently for SSL connection in Data Studio, we need to provide the cert file in .pem file format instead of .crt format.

We can use openssl to convert the cert file.

Perhaps the product team can change the error message to something more meaningful instead of just error ID (the error ID changed for every attempt). Also the documentation is not easy to find pertaining to this issue (didn't come across any)

p/s: will like to vote down whom vote down the question. If the person think the question is of low quality, should at least provide the answer to those whom need it, not just discount others without giving the the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem I was having was to enable TLSv1.1 in MySQL server's configuration.  What it looked like was that Google Data Studio's SSL configuration was not capable of connecting via TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3 versions of the protocol.

This is enabled by including in `/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
tls_version = TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3
```